# Commands Not Showing in Command Palette with RegReplace (Sublime Text 3)

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I'm trying to run a series of commands with the RegReplace plugin in Sublime Text 3 but I cannot get the command to load and I cannot get the keybindings to work either. I have no clue what's wrong.

Steps Taken:

- Installed RegReplace
- Opened the Command Palette
- Searched for "RegReplace: Create New Regular Expression"
- Modified the Rule to the following

  ```
  """
  If you don't need a setting, just leave it as None.
  When the rule is parsed, the default will be used.
  Each variable is evaluated separately, so you cannot substitute variables in other variables.
  """

  # name (str): Rule name.  Required.
  name = "extract_variables"

  # find (str): Regular expression pattern or literal string.
  #    Use (?i) for case insensitive. Use (?s) for dotall.
  #    See https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html for more info on regex flags.
  #    Required unless "scope" is defined.
  find = r".*\[(.*[^(<|>)]*?)\].*"

  # replace (str - default=r'\g<0>'): Replace pattern.
  replace = r"\1"

  # literal (bool - default=False): Preform a non-regex, literal search and replace.
  literal = None

  # literal_ignorecase (bool - default=False): Ignore case when "literal" is true.
  literal_ignorecase = None

  # scope (str): Scope to search for and to apply optional regex to.
  #    Required unless "find" is defined.
  scope = None

  # scope_filter ([str] - default=[]): An array of scope qualifiers for the match.
  #    Only used when "scope" is not defined.
  #
  #    - Any instance of scope qualifies match: scope.name
  #    - Entire match of scope qualifies match: !scope.name
  #    - Any instance of scope disqualifies match: -scope.name
  #    - Entire match of scope disqualifies match: -!scope.name
  scope_filter = None

  # greedy (bool - default=True): Apply action to all instances (find all).
  #    Used when "find" is defined.
  greedy = None

  # greedy_scope (bool - default=True): Find all the scopes specified by "scope."
  greedy_scope = None

  # format_replace (bool - default=False): Use format string style replace templates.
  #    Works only for Regex (with and without Backrefs) and Re (with Backrefs).
  #    See http://facelessuser.github.io/backrefs/#format-replacements for more info.
  format_replace = None

  # selection_inputs (bool -default=False): Use selection for inputs into find pattern.
  #    Global setting "selection_only" must be disabled for this to work.
  selection_inputs = None

  # multi_pass (bool - default=False): Perform multiple sweeps on the scope region to find
  #    and replace all instances of the regex when regex cannot be formatted to find
  #    all instances. Since a replace can change a scope, this can be useful.
  multi_pass = None

  # plugin (str): Define replace plugin for more advanced replace logic.
  plugin = None

  # args (dict): Arguments for 'plugin'.
  args = None

  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # test: Here you can setup a test command.  This is not saved and is just used for this session.
  #     - replacements ([str]): A list of regex rules to sequence together.
  #     - find_only (bool): Highlight current find results and prompt for action.
  #     - action (str): Apply the given action (fold|unfold|mark|unmark|select).
  #       This overrides the default replace action.
  #     - options (dict): optional parameters for actions (see documentation for more info).
  #         - key (str): Unique name for highlighted region.
  #         - scope (str - default="invalid"): Scope name to use as the color.
  #         - style (str - default="outline"): Highlight style (solid|underline|outline).
  #     - multi_pass (bool): Repeatedly sweep with sequence to find all instances.
  #     - no_selection (bool): Overrides the "selection_only" setting and forces no selections.
  #     - regex_full_file_with_selections (bool): Apply regex search to full file then apply
  #       action to results under selections.
  test = {
      "replacements": ["extract_variables"],
      "find_only": True,
      "action": None,
      "options": {},
      "multi_pass": False,
      "no_selection": False,
      "regex_full_file_with_selections": False
  }
  ```

This code Generates the following in AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\reg_replace_rules.sublime-settings

```
{
    "replacements":
    {
        "extract_variables":
        {
            "find": ".*\\[(.*[^(<|>)]*?)\\].*",
            "name": "extract_variables",
            "replace": "\\1"
        }
    }
}
```

And then I created the following command under the same directory with filename Default.sublime-commands

```
[   
    { 
        "caption": "Reg Replace: Extract ERS Variables",
        "command": "extract_ers_variables",
        "args": {
            "replacements": [
                "extract_variables"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

After saving all of this, I still do not see the command in the command palette and it didn't show when I tried to save it as a keymap either.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Came here with my own troubles and may as well document my dumb mistakes. I know nothing of JSON.

When adding two replacements used together going by [the examples at the developer's site](http://facelessuser.github.io/RegReplace/usage/), I could not get the command to show up in the Command Palette. I could get a keybinding to work, but it gave error messages that the first replacement could not be found…after having successfully used it. The culprit was a malformed `reg_replace_rules.sublime-settings` file:

```
//Wrong
{
    "replacements":
    {
        "rep_one":
        //stuff
    },
    "replacements":
    {
        "rep_two":
        //other stuff
    }
}

//Correct
{
    "replacements":
    {
        "rep_one":
        //stuff, comma
        "rep_two":
        //other stuff
    }
}
```

Fixing that cleared up the error message, but the command still would not appear in the Command Palette. The problem there was more bad JSON, this time in `Default.sublime-commands`.

```
//Wrong
{
    "caption": "My Command",
    "command": "reg_replace",
    "args": {"replacements": ["rep_one", "rep_two"]}
}

//Correct
[
    {
        "caption": "My Command",
        "command": "reg_replace",
        "args": {"replacements": ["rep_one", "rep_two"]}
    }
]
```

This is probably obvious to people who have learned JSON properly and use it regularly, and perhaps one day I will be one of those.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this doesn't work for you is that you have the `command` wrong in your `Default.sublime-commands` file. In particular, the command `extract_ers_variables` does not exist, so the entry for it in the command palette is hidden because selecting it wouldn't do anything. Visually speaking, if this command was in a `sublime-menu` file, the entry in the menu would appear disabled.

If you select `Preferences > Package Settings > RegReplace > Quick Start Guide` from the menu and follow through the example that's displayed, note that when it comes to the part about creating the command entry in `Default.sublime-commands`, it tells you to use `reg_replace` as the command, and the name of the `replacements` argument is what tells the command which replacement to do.

As such, your entry should look more like:

```json
[   
    { 
        "caption": "Reg Replace: Extract ERS Variables",
        "command": "reg_replace",
        "args": {
            "replacements": [
                "extract_variables"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Wow. Spent around an hour trying to find the issue. Thanks a lot !!